# How can I calculate resistance from A to C and from A to B in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, resistance, homework, circuits

I've got this circuit, and what I need to do is calculate the equivalent resistance from point A to point C. I've noticed these three resistors are connected in series, but how can I calculate the result? Is it the sum between all three resistors R1+R2+R3, or just the sum between R1 and R3?
[image]

Also, the resistance from A to B is going to consist only of R1? Our teacher also told us that we may go through R2+R3, but it isn't the same result as R1.

Comment: What's your reasoning that the resistance from A to B only consist of R1?

Comment: @TomCarpenter no reasoning. I know I should also include R2 somehow, but I don't know how, exactly

Comment: It can often help to redraw such a circuit but you assumption that this is a series connection configuration is invalid.  This is a combination of series and parallel connected resistors.

Comment: @jwh20 And how can I redraw this circuit? Also thought that R through AB might be R1 - Rpar, where Rpar is the parallel connection between R3 and R2?

Comment: Have you learned how to calculate resistors in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Redraw so that it's clear, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftpEUi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now you should be able to solve for the two cases, R(AC) and R(AB) independently.